# How to get the correct MethodInfo for "Where" extension method

Tags: c#, expression, where-clause, methodinfo

I am trying to get return the correct "Where" extension method using reflection, in order to build a custom Expression. I have tried several ways but the closest I get, throws an exception:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

I know this is because there are two Where methods defined in the Enumrable class - but how can I return the Where method which using only just a predicate of

```
 Func<T, bool>.
```

What I have at the moment is:

```
var collectionType = typeof(TSub);
Type tIEnumerable = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(collectionType);

MethodInfo methodInfo =
        typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethod("Where")                
        .MakeGenericMethod(collectionType);
```

I have also tried (this one returns null):

```
MethodInfo methodWhere = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Where", new[] { typeof(TSub )});
```

and (also returns null)

```
 MethodInfo methodWhere = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Where", new[] { collectionType })
```

and (this one returns the same Ambiguous Exception)

```
MethodInfo methodWhere = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Where", BindingFlags.Public |      BindingFlags.Static)
```

Could anyone help at all please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the current answers, including the accepted one, are far more complicated than necessary. If you have a type `T` that you can use at compile time, you can get the `MethodInfo` like so:

```
Func<IEnumerable<T>, Func<T, bool>, IEnumerable<T>> whereDelegate = Enumerable.Where;
MethodInfo whereMethodInfo = whereDelegate.Method;
```

As an extra bonus, this is strongly typed. It will compile *only* if the `Enumerable.Where` can be resolved, as opposed to anything that looks for a string `"Where"`: that would compile just fine if you accidentally type `"Wehre"` instead, but would fail at runtime.

Comment: Thanks very much, I think you're right. This way works and is less code - thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are easier ways, but here's one:

```
typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
                  .Single(method => method.Name == "Where" 
                          && method.GetParameters()
                                   .ElementAt(1)
                                   .ParameterType
                                   .GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Func<,>)) 
                  .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSub))
```

This is a little brittle though (think Microsoft adding more overloads in a future version of .NET). Perhaps more robust (but even more monstrous; surely there must be a better way) is:

```
var methods = from method in typeof(Enumerable).GetMember("Where")
                                               .OfType<MethodInfo>()                               
              let typeArgs = method.GetGenericArguments()
              where typeArgs.Length == 1
              let typeArg = typeArgs.Single()
              where !typeArg.GetGenericParameterConstraints().Any()
              let seqtype = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeArg)                    
              where method.ReturnType == seqtype
              let expectedParams = new[]
              {
                 seqtype, 
                 typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeArg, typeof(bool))
              }
              where method.GetParameters()
                          .Select(parameter => parameter.ParameterType)
                          .SequenceEqual(expectedParams)

              select method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSub));


var result = methods.Single();
```

Comment: This works, so thanks very much.... now to get this to work in my custom expression ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to tell the two overloads apart is:

```
var whereMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
                .Single(m => m.Name == "Where" && m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Func<,>))
.MakeGenericType(typeof(TSub));
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a template type T, this should work:

```
var methodWhere = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Where", BindingFlags.Public |    BindingFlags.Static, new Type[]{ typeof(IEnumerable<T>), typeof(Func<T, bool>) });
```

The Where method takes two parameters: the IEnumerable and the comparison function.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The above doesn't compile (invalid arguments), so I tried: var methodWhere = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Where", new Type[] {  typeof(IEnumerable<TSub>), typeof(Func<TSub, bool>) });   But this returns null unfortunately. I'll see if I can play around with your idea for the moment and get it to work....